# DOMDocument is producing trailing data in XML

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to create an XML file and then send it as an e-mail as-well as force a download, the problem is that the XML document contains a few random numbers at the end of it, making it useless.

Code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=License.xml');
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $document = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $document->formatOutput = true;
    $element_account = $document->createElement("Account");
    $attr_name = $document->createAttribute("Username");
    $attr_pass = $document->createAttribute("Password");
    $attr_key  = $document->createAttribute("Key");

    $attr_name->value = $user;
    $attr_pass->value = $pass;
    $attr_key->value = $key;

    $element_account->appendChild($attr_name);
    $element_account->appendChild($attr_pass);
    $element_account->appendChild($attr_key);

    $document->appendChild($element_account);

    $file_to_attach = 'tmp/License'.$user.'.xml';

    $document->save($file_to_attach);

    require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $pemail = new PHPMailer();
    $pemail->From      = 'donotreply@OGServer.net';
    $pemail->FromName  = 'OGServer Licensing';
    $pemail->Subject   = 'Your OGServer License has arrived!';
    $pemail->Body      = 'Thank you for registering your product, you will find your License attached to the e-mail, if you have any questions about how to set up your license, you can view the tutorial here: http://ogserver.net/licensing/tutorial.html';
    $pemail->AddAddress( $email );

    $pemail->AddAttachment($file_to_attach, 'License.xml' );

    $pemail->Send();

    $filepath = realpath($file_to_attach);  

    echo readfile($file_to_attach);
```

Comment: You mean numbers auto-generated?

Comment: I would assume, there's just a few random numbers (Usually three of them) at the end of my file, they're different every time i generate a file.

Comment: Can You just post/URL of your sample generated XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output those numbers *after* you've outputted the file to attach. You do that here:

```
echo readfile($file_to_attach);
```

It's just that [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) returns the number of bytes read and you then echo that number. Quoting the section titled Return Values:

> Returns the number of bytes read from the file. If an error occurs, FALSE is returned and unless the function was called as @readfile(), an error message is printed.

As `readfile` has already output the file's content to STDOUT, you just add the integer number of the file-size (bytes read by `readfile`) afterwards.

---

As the file-size actually is not that large, there is even little benefit from using `readfile` here as it requires you to have the file on disk.

So alternatively you can store the XML into a string:

```
$licenseXml = $document->saveXML();
```

And then attach it to the email:

```
$pemail->AddStringAttachment($licenseXml, 'License.xml');
```

and then output it:

```
echo $licenseXml;
```

That should do it equally well.

Comment: Unfortunately the emailing library that I am using doesn't allow me to send a dynamically stored file, which is why I'm writing it to the disk, sending the attatchment, then erasing it from the disk. I'll be able to get a new mailing library once I upgrade my host. Thanks for the explanation though, it helped me fix my problem!

Comment: @Christian.tucker: **PHPMailer** supports that since ages. Otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it, I checked first what the correct methodname is. Let me know if you have any issues with that.

Comment: Strange, for me it states that the parameter value must be a string, and not that of an object. I'll update my library and see if it fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: No, it accepts strings, (`PHPMailer::AddStringAttachment()`) but `$licenseXml` is a string and not an object as you might have thought. It's not the **DOMDocument** object, that would be `$document` in your case. See the code-line `$licenseXml = $document->saveXML();` in the second part of my answer.